# Javascript replace first and last font tag

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm trying to convert html to bbcode.

**My code:**

```
var html = "<font color=\"Green\"><font size=\"4\">test</font></font>"

html = html.replace(/\<font color="(.*?)"\>(.*?)\<\/font\>/ig, "[color=$1]$2[/color]");
```

**Result:**

```
[color=Green]<font size="4">test[/color]</font>
```

**But I need to get another**

```
[color=Green]<font size="4">test</font>[/color]
```

Please could you correct my mistake. Sorry for my English.

Comment: can i ask what you're trying to accomplish? your code looks needlessly complex

Comment: current regex only looks for color, modify and repeat for size.Why the `<font>` tags? They are deprecated

Comment: **charlietfl**, unfortunately it does not help. Because this is an example, sometimes the first "size" and sometimes "color". `<font>` is not my choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use negative lookaheads:

```
html = html.replace(/\<font color="(.*?)"\>(.*?)\<\/font\>(?!\<\/font\>)/ig, "[color=$1]$2[/color]");
```

To explain what's happening here: The pattern I used is exactly yours, except for an appended `(?!\<\/font\>)`. This so-called negative lookahead basically says: "only make this a match, if I don't encounter `</font>` next".

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have difficulty parsing html with regex as you can see from the many many posts on this site about it. Html is not a regular language, and it therefore can be impossible to parse in this way. That being said, if the problem is this simple it should be possible.

Here's a solution that will work in *very* simple cases to get the first and last part

```
var  html = "<font color=\"Green\"><font size=\"4\">test</font></font>"
    ,findTag = /<.*?>|([^<]+)/g
    ,part
    ,allParts = []
    ;
while((part = findTag.exec(html)) !== null) {
  allParts.push(part[0]);
}
console.log(allParts)
var  first = allParts[0]
    ,last = allParts.slice(-1)[0]
    ;
console.log(first, last);
```

You can then parse the first and last as you were doing previously and use `array.join()` to join everything back.

But again, this will only work in the simple case.